How to create 2D drawing blueprint in react?
I'm trying to create a blueprint in React where I can draw lines and get their start and end coordinates, as shown in the picture.

So I've try useing react konvas, but I can't get the right coordinates, so is there a other library or way to do that?
const snapToGrid = (pos) => {
    // 將位置限制在最接近的網格交叉點上
    return {
      x: Math.round(pos.x / gridSize) * gridSize,
      y: Math.round(pos.y / gridSize) * gridSize
    };
  };

const handleMouseDown = (e) => {
    setIsDrawing(true);
    const { x, y } = snapToGrid(e.target.getStage().getPointerPosition());
    setStartPoint({ x, y });
    setEndPoint({ x, y }); // 起點和終點相同
};

const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
    if (!isDrawing) return;
    const { x, y } = snapToGrid(e.target.getStage().getPointerPosition());
    setEndPoint({ x, y });
};

const handleMouseUp = () => {
    setIsDrawing(false);
    // 在滑鼠放開時，將當前繪製的線段添加到線段列表中
    setLines([...lines, { points: [startPoint.x, startPoint.y, endPoint.x, endPoint.y] }]);
};


Hello Julio, can you please provide a small reproducible code snippet ?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

sure! I try to save the coodinates in related to the center of the scene

In my opinion konvas is good compared to others. If you are planning on chaning to other I will suggest Threejs. You can find find more libraries like this from here https://stackshare.io/react-canvas/alternatives.
Happy coding to you.

Hi, yes I'm trying to chaning to react three fiber after drawing 2D  floorplane, but the problem is the coordinates, I can't get the right position (x,y) to convert in to three mesh,
